# Mottie Virtual keyboard, hide native Android Input Keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to use jquery virtual keyboard - http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/mobile.html to create a numbers only input text with a few accelerator keys for a mobile web application.

However I am having a huge issue that is the native android keyboard gets triggered when i press the input box to trigger the on-screen/ virtual keyboard. How do I trigger only virtual keyboard, other plugins can also be used. I have tested a few that all have the same issue.

Perhaps there is a way to disable the input field so it does not trigger the native keyboard but still triggers the on-screen one? making input "readonly" has some issue.

I have the same issue as this other so user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289281/disable-mobile-default-keyboard-to-show-up-using-my-own-virtual-keyboard-web-a however there is no answer to his question.

First attempt

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Virtual Keyboard Basic Demo</title>

    <!-- demo -->
    <link href="demo/demo.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQuery & jQuery UI + theme (required) -->
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- keyboard widget css & script (required) -->
    <link href="css/keyboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery.keyboard.js"></script>

    <!-- keyboard extensions (optional) -->
    <script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
    <!--
    <script src="js/jquery.keyboard.extension-typing.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.keyboard.extension-autocomplete.js"></script>
    -->

    <!-- initialize keyboard (required) -->
    <script>
        $(function(){
            alert("Keyboard ON");
            //$('#keyboard').keyboard();
            $('#keyboard').on('click tap vclick', function (event) {
                //alert("detected touch");
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                event.preventDefault();

                $('#keyboard').keyboard();
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Links to other demo pages & docs -->
    <div id="nav">
        <a href="index.html">Main Demo</a>
        <a class="current" href="basic.html">Basic</a>
        <a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a>
        <a href="layouts.html">Layouts</a>
        <a href="navigate.html">Navigate</a>
        <a href="calculator.html">Calculator</a>
        <a class="play" href="http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/MK947/">Playground</a>
        <a class="git" href="https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki">Documentation</a>
        <a class="git" href="http://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/downloads">Download</a>
        <a class="issue" href="https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/issues">Issues</a><br><br>
    </div>
    <!-- End Links -->

    <div id="wrap"> <!-- wrapper only needed to center the input -->

        <!-- keyboard input -->
        <input id="keyboard" type="text">
        <div><p>Static TEST</p></div>

    </div> <!-- End wrapper -->

</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()` together when you click on the inputbox?

Comment: no I have not, let me try that

Comment: for example `$('input[type=text]').on('click tap vclick', function (event) { event.stopImmediatePropagation(); event.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: I forgot to mention that you should call the virtual keyboard within the above function because it will stop any events/functions attached to the inputbox.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, the keyboard still pops up when you press a key. Ill have to to see what is getting triggered and try to bypass it somehow if at all possible.

Comment: Add the following attribute `readonly="true"`

Comment: Check this http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/hfTQx/

Comment: I will give it a try at work tomorrow with my tablet. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nope does not work, still trying to find a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following code it does appear to work, however more testing is required to make this a solid workaround:

```
$('.keyboard').on('focus click tap vclick', function (event) {
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                event.preventDefault();

                $('.keyboard').blur();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `readonly` to the `<input>` tag, this will stop the native keyboard from appearing. Though remember to remove it for desktop users, which will require some device detection which is never fun.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the global attribute `<div inputmode="none">`,it shoule help.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode